# Is it ok to have a tbody tag with no rows in it and do the browsers add it after if I add a row?

Tags: jquery, html-table

If I have a table with no content but just a header row, is it ok that I have a tbody tag?  For example, if I have:

```
 <table>
       <thead><tr><th>Heading</th><th>Heading 2</th></tr></thead>
       <tbody></tbody>
 </table>
```

or

```
 <table>
       <thead><tr><th>Heading</th><th>Heading 2</th></tr></thead>
 </table>
```

are either of these considered improper html?

I want to apply tbody formatting through CSS so in the second example above if I go add a new row, do I need to add "TBODY" or will the browser automatically add it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) both of your snippets are valid HTML.

I would argue that semantically it makes more sense to include a `<tbody>` element, regardless of whether it has content or not.

Regarding your assumption that browsers insert a `<tbody>` by default, you can't be certain that they all do and if they may or may not in the future.  If you have logic depending on the `<tbody>` element you should definitely include it in your markup to eliminate a potential bug here.